# How to have the console out put string on the right hand margin?

Tags: java

I've been trying to have the console print this

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
```

as

```
                1
               22
              333
             4444
            55555
           666666
```

I've tried using `\t` but that doesn't work.

Comment: You will need to insert spaces.

Comment: You need to handle the number of /t in your logic

Comment: You have to calculate the exact number of spaces for each line and prefix the numbers. Tabs won't work.

Comment: @Draconian: that loop method is better than my one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ( int i = 1 ; i <=6 ; i++ ){
            for( int j = 0 ; j <= 20 - i ; j++ ){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            int k = i ;
            while (k > 0){
                System.out.print(i);
                k--;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Write the required number of space characters before you write the digits.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[String.Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)**

```
String formattedString = String.format("%" + spaceCount + "s", " "); 
//prints spaceCount spaces
System.out.println(formattedString);
```

Increment space-count as necessary between lines, and you will get that many spaces.

Answer (score 1):

There's no good method for doing that, so you'll need to use spaces. But remember that console-windows aren't the same width everytime!

```
String number = /* Your number as string is needed here*/
String outcome = "";
int width = 15;
for(int i = 0; i < width - number.length; i++) {
    outcome += " ";
}
outcome += number;
```

It's bad method, but it should work. Repeat for each number you have.

Answer (score 1):

To use right-justification on the console, you have to know how far over you want it to be. Most terminals are 80 characters wide, so you could do:

```
String.format("%80d", i);
```

If you want less than that, use a number smaller than 80.

Using `String.format` makes java do all the counting work for you.